# Accessing DAO Service methods from non managedbeans

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, managed-bean

I am using Spring 3 and Hibernate 4

How can I use the following in a non ManagedBean

```
@Inject 
EmployeeService employeeService
```

Or if I would want to access DAO method I have to make that a ManagedBean as

```
@Named("mymanagedbean")
@ViewAccessScoped
```

I have a few `Converter` class and in order to access `DAO` service methods  I had to use that as ManagedBean even though they are not ManagedBeans.

What is the best approach to call `DAO` service methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement the Spring interface `ApplicationContextAware` and then set the ApplicationContext. Then you need provide static methods to get the bean instance.

```
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
        throws BeansException {
    CONTEXT = context;
}
    public static Object getBean(String beanName) { ...}
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> arg0) {...}
```

Then in your non-managed bean you can call `SpringApplicationContext.getBean` method by passing in `EmployeeService.class` as the argument or the bean name as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your `Converter` class clean and use dependency *injection* (which is highly recommended in order to be able the test the class easily) instead of the class pulling in its dependencies manually, you can use Spring's ability to configure a pre-existing object created outside of the application context. See the related section in Spring's reference documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example (pertinent to zagyi's answer). Application uses Spring Roo and therefore aspectj.

```
@FacesConverter("example.entity.converter")
@Configurable
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

    @Resource
    MyDAO dao;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value) {

        Entity obj;

        try {
            obj = dao.getEntity(Long.valueOf(value));
        } catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
            throw new ConverterException( message );
        }
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
         Object value) {

        Entity obj = (Entity) value;
        return (obj != null) ? obj.getId().toString() : "";
    }
}
```

---

The dao class

```
@Repository("myDAO")
public class MyDAOImpl implements MyDAO {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the DAO method in `Converter` without `@Inject` using the following and in `EmployeeService` class which implements `Interface` I have defined as `@Service(value="employeeService")`

```
EmployeeService employeeService = 
(EmployeeService)facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null,
"employeeService");
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of api you are using here, but it's not even important. The point I wanted to make in my answer was to say that no matter how you obtain an `EmployeeService` instance in the class that needs it, the class still _pulls in_ its own dependencies. Now try to write a test for that class, and you'll realize, why it's a problem: in the test you have to make sure that there is a full-fledged "facesContext" (whatever it is). A better (or cleaner) approach would be to _inject_ that dependency from outside. The doc I linked explains how you do that with a non-Spring managed object.