# Can instantiate hibernate session Factory directly but cannot do it through spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have started learning hibernate and spring through an assignment in which i am trying to use session factory instance through spring. I understood the hibernate part but just cant go on with spring. I have tried numerous tutorials and examples but just cant get my spring working. Although it works when i instantiate it directly. 
Here are the problem related details of my project...

**applicationContext.xml** (inside WEB-INF)

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.nagarro.training.assignment6.dao.entity.Student" />



<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="studentDAO"
    class="com.nagarro.training.assignment6.dao.impl.StudentDAOImplementation">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>


</beans>
```

**Edit: including changes as suggested**
**StudentDAOImplementaion.java** (the file where it is being used )

```
public class StudentDAOImplementation implements StudentDAO {

    /**
     * single instance of hibernate session
     */
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()

    /**
     * @param sessionFactory
     */
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return the sessionFactory
     */
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
        /**
     * @return list of all the students
     */
    public List<Student> getStudentList() {

        System.out.println(this.getSession().getStatistics());

        return (List<Student>) this.getSEssion.createQuery("from Student")
                .list();
    }

}
```

And here is the snip of my jar files in lib folder:
[image]

I think that i dont need to include hibernate files and beans as it is working fine without spring. Its the spring i cant get to work.I have tried many different implementation from the web but i just cannot get it working. It just says null pointer exception on **       System.out.println(sessionFactory.getStatistics());** line in StudentDAOImplementation.

Test class that calls StudentDAO

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StudentDAOImplementation sd = new StudentDAOImplementation();

    List<Student> list = sd.getStudentList();

    for(Student s : list) {
        System.out.println(s.getName());
    }
}
```

}

**Stack trace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StudentDAOImplementation.getStudentList(StudentDAOImplementation.java:116)
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

Comment: can you share the stack trace

Comment: Have you tried @RyanStewart 's solution

Comment: Can you share the `Test` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sessionFactory` variable is misleadingly named, since the type is actually `Session`. `Session` != `SessionFactory`. You're getting a NPE on `sessionFactory.getStatistics()` because there's no way that Spring can autowire a Session into a DAO like that. If you're not seeing an error before the NPE, then you're not actually instantiating the DAO with Spring, or else you'd get an error about not being able to find a dependency of type Session. The appropriate way to use a Hibernate-based DAO is to inject it with a `SessionFactory` and call `getCurrentSession()` in your methods where you need a `Session`. See ["Implementing DAOs based on plain Hibernate 3 API"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight) and following for details about this approach and about setting up appropriate transaction management.

**Update:** On a second glance, I see that the package for your component-scan is set to `com.nagarro.training.assignment6.dao.entity.Student`, which looks exactly like a class, not a package. It's also not even close to anything you'd actually want to component-scan. Maybe you don't understand what component-scan is for. It's covered under ["Annotation-based container configuration"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) in the reference guide.

**Update 2:** About your "test" code: you're not using Spring at all, so you might as well remove the XML and save yourself the trouble. On the other hand, if you'd like to actually use Spring, you'd need to create a context in your main method based on said XML file, such as:

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(locationOfXmlFile);
```

Then if you want a Spring-managed DAO, you can't just create one with `new`. Spring isn't magic. It doesn't grab control away from you just because you have it loaded somewhere in the same JVM.* You have to ask Spring for the DAO that *it* created, like:

```
StudentDAO dao = context.getBean(StudentDAO.class);
```

Note that I used the interface type, not the concrete type. That's always an advisable practice for numerous reasons.

This (not starting Spring) is your first problem. As soon as you do this, you're going to run into other problems with your configuration. You should post a new question if you need help solving one of them.

*Unless you're [using AspectJ weaving to inject arbitrary objects](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable).

Comment: You are right, but should spring throw an exception saying unable to find a dependency of type Session

Comment: It should, yes, but the OP says nothing about how Spring is initialized or how the DAO is obtained. There are any number of wrong ways to do things and only a handful of correct ways.

Comment: Yes, My assumption is he is not using applicationContext, he is using new operator to get the dao

Comment: Included the test class. Earlier i thought that test class is irrelevant but now it seems that it does. Would there be a difference if i invoke the DAO class with new ??
Also, should i be using the @Autowired on the setter method or on the sessionFactory ??

Comment: Updated my answer to account for `Test`. You can use @Autowired on the setter, the field, or a constructor. It makes little difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot ryan. You found exactly what was wrong with my code. And yes i ran into several other problems after that but solved them all with Google. Most of them were version related. It is pretty hard for a beginner to learn a new framework like spring with all the tutorials on the net not taking care of different versions..

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting a `Session` instead of `SessionFactory` with `@Autowired private Session sessionFactory;` in the DAO class. It needs to be a `SessionFactory` , like this
 `@Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory;`

And then use it like this to do a DAO operations like save

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
session.persist(entity);
```

**EDIT**

Your testcase should be something like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:<path_to_your_appcontext.xml>" })
public class StudentDAOTest {

@Autowired
private StudentDAO studentDAO

@Test
public void test() {
      List<Student> list = studentDAO.getStudentList();
      assertNotNull(list)
}
}
```

Comment: Included all the changes as suggested by you. But still i get the same NPE. Its like its not taking the spring at all. Is there something which i am doing wrong with the placement of xml file or something else

Comment: In your test class are you creating the Spring bean like this - <code>StudentDAOImplementation sd = new StudentDAOImplementation();</code>, then it is not a Spring Managed Bean. You need to get this bean instance from the Spring's ApplicationContext

Comment: I have included the code of the test class in my question and yes i am instantiating the StudentDAOImplementation with new keyword

Comment: If you instantiate a Spring Bean with new keyword, then it is not a Spring Instantiated bean instance. Please see my edited answer with the test case.

Comment: I included your solution but still no luch. The RunWith and Contextonfiguration annotations are giving me a lot of errors, so i dropped them. No other sample application i tried mentions them anyway. I dont understand why is it not working for me.

Comment: @ishan - That is a junit test case, you need to add junit and spring-test dependencies to your project. I am assuming you are comfortable with those. You cannot test your Spring DAO's like you have given in the Test Class. Or else you will have to implement ApplicationContextAware interface and then use that implementation to instantiate the DAO object. Please look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128228/accessing-dao-service-methods-from-non-managedbeans/15128469#15128469

Comment: I hate to sound hopeless but i tried everything you said with no luck. I believe there is something small that i am doing wrong..