# Unable to initialize spring through ContextLoaderListener in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Please refer to the question - [Can instantiate hibernate session Factory directly but cannot do it through spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194860/can-instantiate-hibernate-session-factory-directly-but-cannot-do-it-through-spri/15195373)

In that question i was unable to initiate spring at all. It was resolved after someone suggested that i should use ApplicationContext to initiate spring. But this approach requires me to use ApplicationContext and then the bean every time i have to get an instance. What i want is that spring injects all the beans into their place and i get to use them anywhere i want. So i put this into my web.xml

```
<listener> <!-- For struts2-spring to work -->
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

But this is not working for me at all. Its giving me null pointer exception wherever the bean injected object has been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard web.xml file should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Compare your version of web xml with this one and see if your xml files containing those beans are getting initialized properly. You can analyze the stack trace printed when application starts.

Comment: This is a correct answer. But my problem lies somewhere else which i was not able to find. I started a new project from scratch in a different IDE and it worked.